# Unable to read the output file in python

Tags: python, information-retrieval, data-retrieval

Unable to read the output file. The code seems perfect, but neither im getting desire result nor im getting an error. Please help me on this

Note: I'm getting the result as blank space as i print

```
with open("D:/txt_res/RahulChoudhary.txt") as infile, open ("x", 'w') as outfile:

    copy = False

    for line in infile:

        if line.strip() == "Technical Skills":

            copy = True

        elif line.strip() == "Work Experience":

            copy = False

        elif copy:

            outfile.write(line)

            infile = open("x", 'r')

            contents = infile.read()

            print(contents)
```

Comment: why close outfile in the for loop? you need 'a' mode?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Neither there is an error nor it is getting executed

Comment: Can you update the question with the infile ?

Comment: You shouldn't close outfile in the loop, or you won't be able to write to it at all after one line has been written.

Comment: @LittleQ As far as i know, we have to close the outfile so that the write function runs properly and writes the output to 'x'.

Comment: Where is `f` defined?

Comment: I assume that `f` from `for line in f` should actually be `infile`.

Comment: @AnandSKumar update with infile? didnt get you? you mean you want the complete input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your specified requirements in the comments, I've updated my code. It searches for "Technical Skills" in each line, and once found, enables writing (`copy`). It will write every line once this one is hit, and when a line with "Work Experience" is found, it stops processing.

```
with open("in.txt") as infile, open ("out.txt", 'w') as outfile:

    copy = False

    for line in infile:

        if line.strip() == "Technical Skills":
            copy = True

        if line.strip() == 'Work Experience':
            break

        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)

fh = open("out.txt", 'r')
contents = fh.read()
print(contents)
```

Given this input:

```
Introduction
I'm me, I'm not sane, I do reckless things most of the time, and I have a
very hard time keeping focused on tasks.

Technical Skills
- I have this skill
- and this skill
- I suck at these skills
- but I'm very good at this, that and the other too

Work Experience
2001 - 2010 Senior Network Engineer
2010 - 2015 Senior Toilet Cleaner
```

It will produce this output:

```
Technical Skills
- I have this skill
- and this skill
- I suck at these skills
- but I'm very good at this, that and the other too
```

If you don't want the "Technical Skills" line in the output, put a line with `continue` directly after the `copy = True` line.

Comment: Still im not getting the required output. When im typing in spyder, im getting blank space and if i type the code in python.exe then i'm getting some numbers as output, whereas my output has to be text.

Comment: Well, considering you didn't post any of your original input data, that's bound to happen. All this script does is read a file and loop over it. If a line in the file has "Technical Skills" in it, it writes that line to the output file. Once the input file is done, the output file is printed. If "Technical Skills" isn't in the input file, the output file will be blank, and nothing will print. If you told us what your input is and what *exactly* you want as output, that would really help.

Comment: The input file is a resume which has titles like "Technical Skills", "Work Experience" etc, what i want to achieve here is, strip the data starting from Technical Skills till Work Experience. I'm getting the result if i give a output path and create a text file in that path, as mentioned here --> "with open("D:/txt_res/RahulChoudhary.txt") as infile, open("D:/txt_res/sample.txt", 'w') as outfile:"

Comment: But i dont want to manually create a path and create a text file everytime and then save the output, rather i want to run this automatically. And that is why i want to save the output to a Variable like 'x' before saving it to text or csv as i have to do further analysis.

Comment: I've updated my code with more of what you need in my answer here.

Comment: If you want to do something with the lines caught, do them in the `if copy:` block. If you want them saved for later, define a list above the open commands (and remove the opening of the outfile), and in the `if copy` block, append each line to the list. You can process this list after the `with open` block ends.

Comment: If i have to continue stripping the same infile with further titles, is it possible to continue in the same loop or I have to start a new loop again with "with open (path) infile"?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the loop should be:

```
for line in infile:
```

Next, as Christopher Shroba and others mentioned, you should not handle the opening/closing of the file in the for loop. The "with" keyword is a handler, so it will deal with opening and closing the files. Just write the line to it as you are already.

This goes for the infile as well. "With" is handling it, so you do not need to open or close it manually.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my code. But still im not getting output, im getting blank space or some numbers